# Streaming pulseaudio to Internet

Tags: pulseaudio, internet-radio

I want to transmit my PC pulseaudio (music) through Internet, from a WineHQ audio app.

The app is sounding in my speakers and all looks so fine!!!

Which Ubuntu software I have to use to take that audio and put it into the Internet Audio Streaming Service???

Answer (score 1):

OBS Will achieve this. Download [Here](https://obsproject.com/download).
Although, this will not be thru a Wine HQ App. I will delete this answer if you are specifically looking for this. (I suppose you could install OBS as a Windows App, but I do not recommend this type of installation)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to say that I use a WineHQ app because I don't know to use other. The app does all the work, to play my music lists and other "events" (station identification phrases). So... I need to "take" that audio (pulseaudio) and to put it into the Internet.

Comment: Yes, OBS can take your Audio output and stream it to a lot of popular sites! Enjoy!

Comment: I downloaded and Installed OBS Studio but... It is a too much complex Audio-Video Studio software!!! I was thinking about an small, specific, direct to the point, Ubuntu app. Isn't there some one???

Comment: BTW: I also use PulseEffects Audio Processing Ubuntu app, so that app is my final pulseaudio "connection point". It is the audio I want to put into the Internet (OBS Studio doesn't include the audio server I use, and I'm not sure if we can add some extra server and its parameters)

Comment: Not sure if this is any less complex but it is run from the command line. I am not experienced with UPnP/DLNA, so I can't help you there. http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/how-to-stream-audio-to-chromecast-or.html

Answer (score 1):

for just audio connection to stream
[darksnow](http://darksnow.radiolivre.org/index.en.html)
or 
[butt - broadcast using this tool](http://danielnoethen.de/)

also [Mixxx](https://mixxx.org/) can stream to icecast/shoutcast

but if you install the JACK audio server there is [Internet DJ Controller](http://idjc.sourceforge.net/tour_main.html)

audio processing effects in Pulseffects were originally from JACK

JACK is for professional low latency audio and capable of running everything you could need for a radio station. JACK can be tricky to get configured but is very reliable once set correctly. sound quality should be better than anything in Wine or Pulseaudio